# Rails Exceptions - Add ENV to Exception Text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I'm using exceptional.io to get emails for all the exceptions occuring in my rails app, however I was hoping to rewrite all the Exception Texts so that the subject of the email shows the ENV that the error occured in.

Currently we get something like this:
appName: Plans Controller# ...more error text

I'd love to get something like this:
appName: DEV::Plans Controller# ...more error text or 
appName: PROD::Plans Controller# ...more error text

Can you just hook into the application controller to do something like this?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    rescue from Exception, with => cool_exception_hook

    def cool_exception_hook 
        //not sure what to do here?
        Exception.text = ENV + "::" + Exception.text
        //continue executing as before....
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use the Exceptional.context. See:
http://support.exceptional.io/kb/extras/sending-extra-data-to-exceptional.

Also, look at this example of how can you filter or inject:
http://support.exceptional.io/kb/extras/filtering-sensitive-data

Comment: For sure, I looked at that and it works fine in the body of the email from Exceptional - would be ultimate to have it in the subject with the text of the Exception so that it was easily sortable too inside of gmail or whatnot.

Comment: Probably the simple answer is to setup 2 seperate exceptional apps with different names to show the PROD / DEV and then it filter based on that - I just thought it would be cool to use the 1 account but add the data using ruby on rails to allow filtering -

Comment: Did i point you to the right direction? if so accept the answer :) or at-least up-vote